# Registering an async javascript, declarative (static) vs dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

Is there any difference in declaring my `async` javascript statically vs dynamically?

**static**

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <div id='my-script-needs-me'></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://foo.bar/myscript.js" async>
  </script>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

**dynamic**

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <div id='my-script-needs-me'></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var myScript = document.createElement("script");
      myScript.src = 'https://foo.bar/myscript.js';
      myScript.async = !0;
      myScript.type = 'text/javascript';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(myScript);
  </script>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

I noticed that declaring a script statically let a browser detect it earlier and preload (chrome + firefox).

My goal is to load a javascript in `async` way in order not to block HTML rendering and other scripts execution. Sametime, I want it to be executed as soon as it's downloaded, having in mind that it requires one element to be in the DOM already. Once downloaded the script is executed and it accesses the `my-script-needs-me` div. One limitation, I cannot change the script itself.

Comment: you can put this in a callback for window.DOMContentLoaded

Comment: put what? I wouldn't like to way for the DOMContentLoaded coz there are plenty of another script loading before and after my script. I want to start loading the script as soon as possible and execute it once my div is in DOM without waiting for the rest of DOM to be completed.

Comment: if you require the dom element to already in place, just place your script directly after the element

Comment: I did it. Another requirements I won't like my script to block other scripts that is why I made it `async` and now my question what is the difference between static and dynamic script declaration

Comment: dynamic script declaration is non-blocking, whereas static script declaration without async tag blocks until it is evaluated completely

Comment: hence there is no difference if I declare the `async` attribute on my static script? Why do I see different performance then? My statically declared script is downloaded earlier (when dom starts loading a browser kicks off the request) than dynamically created (the request is kicked off only when dom reached the script tag).

Comment: yes, there is no difference. appendChild is asynchronous.

Comment: there should be a difference because when I check my network requests I can see that with static way to declare the script it appears earlier in the requests list (and downloaded earlier as a result). I guess the key here is that browser (e.g. chrome) can see the script declaration in advance and make some arrangement to download it even before we reach the point of script declaration.

Comment: very interesting. it makes sense because async will have the browser immediately begin fetching the script in a separate thread, whereas dynamic declaration will push the method onto the execution queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

supports async parameters allowing to make this call asynchronous.

The second way you described allows you to have the url as a parameter and bind it.
It allows too the use of a callback to do some stuff when your script is loaded.

```
let scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
let url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${apiKey}`;//&libraries=geometry
  scriptElement.src = url;
  //Chargement de l'API Google
  scriptElement.onload = () => {
    //API chargée, on peut lancer l'initialisation du composant
    this._initializeMap();
  };
```

I used this to load Google Maps API, it's not directly in the HTML, so i can modify the URL when my page loads. And when the API is loaded, I an launch treatments that need this API.

Comment: I can you `load` callback with `static` script declaration as well. The only this is about dynamic url, that's true, you can have it only with the `dynamic` script tag creation. My question is more about performance, but your point is totally valid and clear.

Comment: I believe that static declaration is faster. With dynamic, you create a static link, but you have to count the time required for creating the script tag. So, static is faster.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `defer` for that instead of async.

your script will execute right after `html` be parsed.

Comment: I want to execute the script once it's loaded and don't want to wait until the whole page is parsed.

Comment: You can place your `script` tag at the top of `head` tag. And you can use IIFE to execute your code immediately.

Comment: I cannot place my script tag at the top of the `head` because it requires the `my-script-needs-me` element to present at the page.

Comment: Could you please clarify how `IIFE` makes the difference?

Comment: `IIFE` will be the same as function call. you can check the speed here https://jsperf.com/iife-vs-iife-call-vs-named-vs-declare/1

Answer (score 1):

**Static**

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <div id='my-script-needs-me'></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://foo.bar/myscript.js" async>
  </script>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

As you know, HTML is parsed top-bottom. So, if it placed within body tag, then as soon as parsed, if it is an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) or the file `myscript.js` contains a `function call`, it will execute immediately.

So, inside, `body`, put it the script at the bottom will help you to execute it after the `div` has loaded.

But we can't ensure because of caching.

If the browser cache the script and if it is an IIFE or contains a function call, we can't predict the behaviour.

#### Dynamic

In dynamic also, it depends on the order.

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <div id='my-script-needs-me'></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var myScript = document.createElement("script");
      myScript.src = 'https://foo.bar/myscript.js';
      myScript.async = !0;
      myScript.type = 'text/javascript';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(myScript);
  </script>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

In both cases, it will render after HTML contents.

The best way to ensure it loads only after all contents are loaded is

Giving an `eventListener` on Window.

Check the code below

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <div id='my-script-needs-me'></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function load(){
        var myScript = document.createElement("script");
        myScript.src = 'https://foo.bar/myscript.js';
        myScript.async = !0;
        myScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(myScript);
     }
     window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",load);
  </script>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

Check this line  `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",load);`.

The [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) is similar to jQuery's `$(document).ready()`. It will trigger the callback function when the HTML is properly loaded. So, you don't have to check for the existence of the HTML Element.

Comment: from my tests, even if the script is cached (static approach) it won't be executed earlier than declared. And another thing, the `DOMContentLoaded`, as well as the bottom of the page, would work if there is no other code after my script but there are plenty of it and I would like to make it's not preventing my `async` script from executing once my `div` is rendered.

Comment: @AlexeyStrakh then, in the head, add an eventlistener to the window for 100 mS and in the callback, check if the div is undefined or not. if not, clear the eventListener and start the execution.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've learned it's better to go with `static` way to declare an async script (in my particular scenario) than `dynamic`. Here some of why(s):

1. `static async` script declaration is detected by a browser and kicked off right away (at the very top of the page processing);
2. (deferred from #1) a browser puts the script request earlier in requests queue and if you have enough (30-40 requests per page load) it could be crucial to be in first 10 requests, not at the position 30-40;
3. adding a script dynamically to the `head` from the `body` doesn't introduce any performance advantage against the `static` declaration as long as whole `head` is already processed and it won't delay execution of the statically declared script;
4. at the moment when we reach the script declaration, `static` will work instantly because it's already pre-loaded and ready to be executed (in most cases, `async` is crucial here) while the `dynamic` script declaration will just kick off the request to download the script and only after then execute it;

I hope my thoughts will help someone as well.